# How to get ids of all checked checkbox on button click using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<html>  
    <input type='checkbox' id='1' name='checkMr[]' value='1' />       
    <input type='checkbox' id='2' name='checkMr[]' value='2' />            
    <input type='checkbox' id='3' name='checkMr[]' value='3' />         
    <input type='checkbox' id='4' name='checkMr[]' value='4' />        

    <a id="savedoctorschedule" style="float: right;" class="clyes clbutton clbtnSave">Save</a>       
</html> 

<script>
$j("#savedoctorschedule").bind("click", function () { 
    $j.ajax({
        url: "schedulemr.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { schmrid: $j("#sel_mr").val(), 
        schedocid: $j("#checkMr[]").val(), 
        schedate: $j("#date1").val(), },
        success:function(response){         
        }
</script>

<?php
include '../includes/include.php';
$schmrid = $_POST['sel_mr'];
$schedate = $_POST['date1'];
$schedocid = $_POST['checkMr'];
foreach($schedocid as $a => $b)
{
   $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_mr_schedule(doctor_idscheduled_date) 
   VALUES ('".$schedocid[$a]."','".$schmrid."','0','".$date."','".$schedate."');";
   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
header('Location:../visitplan/');
?>
```

I want all the ids of checked checkboxes using jQuery; the checkbox may be `n` number. I want to insert the checked checkboxes' value in the database where the number of records will depend upon the number of checked checkbox. This would be using PHP as server-side script.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Try below,

```
$(':checkbox[name="checkMr[]"]:checked') //returns you the list of selected checkbox
```

then you can,

```
var selectedID = [];
$(':checkbox[name="checkMr[]"]:checked').each (function () {
    selectedID.push(this.id);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/ww7us/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#savedoctorschedule").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var sList = "";
    $('input[name="checkMr[]"]').each(function () {
        if(this.checked){
            sList += "(" + $(this).attr('id') + ")";
        }
    });
    alert(sList);
    }
);​
```

Please find the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u2Mds/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Your document is invalid for several reasons. Skipping the obvious (missing doctype/`<body>`/etc), the id attribute may not begin with a number; `id="1"` is invalid. You'll have to use a non-numeric prefix like `id="check-1"` or by assigning the ID as the `value` of the checkbox.

Once you've fixed this, you can use the following to find all checked checkboxes, and retrieve their value (or whichever attribute you choose to use).

```
$("input:checked").map(function () { return $(this).val(); });
```

Comment: this ids are assigned dynamicly from table's record id. so it is numeric

Comment: It **can't** be numeric. It won't work. This is what I'm telling you. You'll have to use another attribute or add a `check-` prefix, which you strip away.

Comment: Most browsers will recognize numeric `id` values, even though they're disallowed in HTML 4. (HTML5 allows them.) [See for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/aRJc7/). It's a bad  habit but it's unlikely to break any code.

Answer (score 0):

Id's cannot start with numbers. Once you've updated the id's use attr('value') or .val() to retrieve the value associated with the input.

Comment: To solve your original questions use the following code to query all checked elements:

$('.input-container input:checked');

Then use a for loop or jQuery's .each() function to loop over the returned elements and extract the data you need.